# Collapse a popup menu when user clicks outside the menu

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a CSS drop menu without using JavaScript , and after researching I've found this code 
http://jsfiddle.net/zsp7t/1/

```
<div class="dropdown" id="dropdown">
    <input type="checkbox" id="drop1" />
    <label for="drop1" class="dropdown_button">
        <img src="http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/wwfeatures/43_43/images/live/p0/17/tx/p017txf6.jpg" height="43" width="43" /><span id="arrowSpan" class="arrow"></span>
    </label>
    <ul class="dropdown_content">
        <li><a href="#">Privacy settings</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Account settings</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Logout</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and here's the CSS

```
body {
    background-color: white;
    font: normal 11px Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    color: #222;
    height: 380px;
}

#arrowSpan{
    display:block;
    margin-left:17px;
    margin-top:2px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}

.dropdown {
    display: block;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 3px;
    position: relative;
}
/* ===[ For demonstration ]=== */
 .dropdown {
    margin-top: 25px
}
/* ===[ End demonstration ]=== */
 .dropdown .dropdown_button {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #717780;
    line-height: 16px;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    background: white;
}
.dropdown input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .dropdown_button {
    border: 1px solid #3B5998;
    color: white;
    background: silver;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px 2px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 2px 2px 0px 0px;
    border-bottom-color: silver;
}
.dropdown input[type="checkbox"] + .dropdown_button .arrow {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    border-top: 5px solid silver;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
}
.dropdown input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .dropdown_button .arrow {
    border-color: white transparent transparent transparent
}
.dropdown .dropdown_content {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #777;
    padding: 0px;
    background: white;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
    right:0;
}
.dropdown .dropdown_content li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 0px;
    line-height: 16px;
    border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
.dropdown .dropdown_content li:hover {
    background: silver;
}
.dropdown .dropdown_content li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 2px 7px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.dropdown .dropdown_content li:hover a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
.dropdown input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .dropdown_content {
    display: block
}
.dropdown input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none
}
```

which works perfect for me ... the only problem is that i want the user when clicking outside on blank area the list disappear (uncheck box) 
so any help ?

note:i don't want use any JavaScript

Comment: You cannot, as the toggler is bound to the same source..

Comment: You could instead use a `<a>` tag with destination `#`, and use its `:focus` selector, maybe?

Comment: While this is an interesting way to create a drop-down menu, it breaks the semantic logic of the page completely.

Comment: @Nit, I agree, see my answer for a little (very little) more semantic version. If the questioner wants semantics, he should use JavaScript to handle this, or become a CSS black magician.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `<a>` tag with no target (only hash on `href`) and make use of its `:focus` attribute:
HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/sVxxZ/1/

```
<span class="dropdown">
    <a href="#">
        Dropdown
    </a>
    <span class="dropdown_content">asdf</span>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown_content {
    display: none;
}
.dropdown a:focus + .dropdown_content {
    display: block;
}
```

`<a>` tags (links) have a special behaviour that is receiving the `:focus` pseudo-class when they are clicked, until the user clicks something else. In IE and some older versions of Firefox and Chrome, for example, this was used to add a dotted border around the last clicked link. Clicking anywhere else would dismiss this border.

This was later standardised into the `:focus` pseudo-class, that is applied to usable elements (inputs, links, etc) when they are clicked/touched/tabbed into until they get out of focus (user clicks/touches/tabs away) something else. Links (`<a>` elements) also require a `href` attribute to be clickable (usable).

By setting the `href` to `#`, we tell the browser to navigate to this page to the anchor named (yes, nothing). Since this anchor doesn't exist, nothing happens, but the link is still clickable, and thus will be applied the `:focus` pseudo-class while focused.

We have the `dropdown_content` being with `display:none`, so it is hidden by default. With this, we use a sibling selector `+` to select a element with the class `dropdown_content` that has a `:focus`ed link right before it (in the HTML), and set its `display` to `block`, a visible value. When the user clicks something else (including anything in the menu), the menu closes, because the link will not have its `:focus`.

If you would like to have the menu stay open if the user clicks inside it, you will have to change the CSS selectors a bit (actually just remove the `+`) and put the menu `<div>` inside the `<a>` tag.

Your original fiddle with the alterations necessary: http://jsfiddle.net/zsp7t/32/

Comment: i can't get the logic you're trying to explain !!

Comment: @HossamDin Will explain this better, wait a few mins

Comment: okaiii , actually the logic sounds working ... but the code ain't i was trying to edit it but no result

Answer (score 0):

Use the label as overlay. Tho I would have prefered to use JS.

```
<div class="dropdown" id="dropdown">
    <input type="checkbox" id="drop1" />
    <label for="drop1" class="dropdown_button">
        <img src="http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/wwfeatures/43_43/images/live/p0/17/tx/p017txf6.jpg" height="43" width="43" /><span id="arrowSpan" class="arrow"></span>
    </label>
    <span class="dropdown_button_dummy">
        <img src="http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/wwfeatures/43_43/images/live/p0/17/tx/p017txf6.jpg" height="43" width="43" /><span id="arrowSpan" class="arrow"></span>
    </span>
    <div class="ddw">
        <ul class="dropdown_content">
            <li><a href="#">Privacy settings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Account settings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Remove `position: relative;` from `.dropdown` to make the label relative to body.

```
.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown .dropdown_button {
    display: inline-block;
   /* Style */
}

.dropdown .dropdown_button_dummy {
    display: none;
}

.dropdown input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .dropdown_button_dummy {
    display: inline-block;
    /* Style */
}

.dropdown input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .dropdown_button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
    /* Remove styles */
}

.dropdown .ddw {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.dropdown input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .ddw > .dropdown_content {
    display: block
}

.dropdown input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none
}
```

Since you lose the dropdown button create a dropdown_button_dummy to replace the label